# Xcode 4 organization, Views and Controllers

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Thank you for reading this.

These are my first steps in the iPhone Ipad app programming.
In order to learn from scratch (and because I know my app would need dynamic views), I decided not to use Interface Builder.

My question is(regarding the fact that I don't use IB): how would one use Views and Controllers?

I think I understand the MVC concept as it is repeated over and over again in the tutorials I follow,  but after the "MVC explanation" part, nothing is made to make it clear "on the field" and closer to the real world (Earth being Xcode here).
Worse, sometimes it seems that some tutorials mix these two concepts up and use one word to say the other.

I read around here a lot of questions (and answers of course) based on the matter but I still don't get it. Sometimes it's too generic, sometimes it's too specific (for me at least).

For what I think I understood, the UIView is the static View when the View Controller is the logic which links the View to the data and those 3 concepts must be separated.
This separation, while a bit clearer with the use of Interface Builder seems to get quite blurry when you code everything as it becomes a virtual soup.

Technically, should I create a specific ".h" and ".m" file for each View AND ALSO for each associated Controller?
If I understand the MVC pattern, it's seems that I should but when I follow tutorials (without IB) it is never the case, view and controllers are created and manipulated within the same implementation files.

Any high level (I'm a noob, don't forget) but still applicable explanation of the use and best practices?

Let's say I want to create a simple app with a green view I can swipe to get to a red view.
I know for sure that I would need at least an:

- xxxappDelegate.h
- xxxappDelegate.m
- xxxView.h
- xxxView.m

What else?

1)Where should I put the the second view (along with the first one in "xxxView" or should I create another class h and m file?)?

2) What would the controller(s) do, for that kind of application? In which files would they be created and in which files would they be invoked and how would they "control" the related view?

3) Mainly, regarding to MVC pattern and the fact that there would be no IB, how would you organize that app?

I know it's a lot if you go into the details and code but that's not the point here.

Thank you. This - as simple as it seems - would be of a great help and is not as easily found in tutorials as you might think.
I understand the tutorials I read but they are so particular. As soon as I try to create something on my own which is not a "Hello World" screen, I realize that something is missing, logic wise.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Early:

> In order to learn from scratch (and because I know my app would need
>   dynamic views), I decided not to use Interface Builder.

Later:

> As soon as I try to create something on my own which is not a "Hello
>   World" screen, I realize that something is missing, logic wise.

I think what is missing logic wise is that you have accepted your assumption that Interface Builder was a crutch and that to learn "from scratch" you had to avoid using it. You are trying to learn the MVC design pattern but you are not willing to use the tools that have been designed to support it.

In [Apple's own documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1) they discuss the fact that sometimes there is value in having combined roles—Model Controllers and View Controllers—and that is worth reading, as it may explain some of the code examples you're reviewing. But my primary advice would be: before assuming you know better than the people who built the tools, trying using them the way they recommend. It might be an eye-opener.

Additions later:
OK, so to try and actually answer your questions...

> 1)Where should I put the the second view (along with the first one in
>   "xxxView" or should I create another class h and m file?)?

If I am understanding correctly and the two views you are thinking of here are the red and the blue displays to the user, you wouldn't have a second view—what you would do, whether in IB or in code—is to have an element in your view on which you changed a colour property... This would be done programmatically whether you were setting up the parent view in IB or in code.

> 2) What would the controller(s) do, for that kind of application? In
>   which files would they be created and in which files would they be
>   invoked and how would they "control" the related view?

There would be a view controller that would implement the gesture support, and would provide a method for changing the colour of the item in the view between blue and red when that swipe gesture was successfully received. I would have a ViewController.h and and ViewController.m. I think if you were implementing the View entirely in code, it would be implemented in the ViewController.m rather than having a separate View.m. (If you were using IB, you would have a ViewController.h, ViewController.m and ViewController.xib, with the latter providing the basic setup of the view elements and layers.)

You would create a ViewController instance in your AppDelegate.

> 3) Mainly, regarding to MVC pattern and the fact that there would be
>   no IB, how would you organize that app?

As above.

Comment: I don't assume I know better than anyone. What I assume is that if I ask how to prepare sushis, I expect recipes, not evangelist telling me how wrong it is to eat raw fish instead (with quite a pressure!). Is it possible to code without IB? Yes! Even if it's weird, even if it's time consuming, even if I use the keyboard with my feet, why do you care? Are you so worried that a guy you don't know becomes a bad developer? You seem to have some experience here so you should know better than me that opinion debates are not allowed, yet, that's all I got. I'm not better than you, I'm just different.

Comment: This being said, I thank you for your interesting input. It's just the "you know better than..." that annoyed me a little.

Comment: It's more a case of wanting to make sushi and deciding to breed fish instead of using ones from the market.  Sometimes to start with, you can go too low level.  IB is a powerful tool and building with it to start with helps you understand the concepts better as it guides you to some degree.  Then once you understand how to build with it you can riff off those ideas with custom approaches...

Comment: I got it and I know all of you are right. But read my new answer somewhere above and you'll get why I do it my way. But the fact that you are right doesn't mean I'm wrong. When I draw a rectangle, make it red, give it a dimension and a position, I like to know how this could be achieved by code. With IB, as good as it is, I read how to click. At some point I will learn how to give a rectangle a color. For most people, they prefer to learn it afterwards. Me, I prefer to learn it as a prior. Yes I like to breed fish. It's foolish but it's way more instructive for me, that's it.

Comment: I appreciate the point, and am not wanting to get into an opinion debate. From my reading though, your three specific questions are really only asking about opinion anyway—how should I organise my classes for best effect (while not using IB)?—so an answer that is based in opinion is not altogether unwarranted. Whether a reply contains code or discussion, it would not be unheard of to be suggesting that the person asking the question check the underlying assumptions. But I apologize for having caused offence.

Comment: No offense at all! You will appreciate the fact that the two people who gave me their opinions about organizing the code were thanked deeply. Both of them also told me what they strongly think about using IB. As part of an answer it's fine. It only becomes hard to swallow when the answer doesn't answer anything that has been asked in the first place. Regards. (Sorry for the spelling and mistakes, english is not my mother tongue).

Comment: I presume that when desiring to not use IB, the templates that come with XCode would usually seem unusable? It may however be useful to look at the code organisation approaches used in those template files, even if you then intend to re-implement what they have in the xib files using code...

Comment: That's interesting indeed. What I use for my experiments is a Window Based App from which I delete de MainView.xib and then recreate the window and main view on my own. The templates are a great start to learn the logic behind an app but they still involve a great deal of nib files. It's different but at a very high level, I could learn something from them. My main issue is that, if I understand the tutorials I follow, they all use their techniques to explain a small portion of what apps development is about. When I gather all of what I learn and try to extract a common logic of it, I'm lost.

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you very much duncan-babbage! That's as clear as crystal!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but I can't get past your first paragraph. If you don't use Interface Builder, you are not going to be a successful iOS programmer. It's that simple. The best advice I've ever read about this is in [this Aaron Hillegass interview](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1220319):

> Experienced Cocoa programmers put a lot of the smarts of their application in the NIB file. As a result, their project has a lot less code. Programmers who have spent a few years working in Visual Studio get freaked out. They ask me stuff like, "Can I write Cocoa apps without using Interface Builder? I like to see the code. Maybe I can just explicitly create my windows and the views that go on it?"
>
> It is difficult to explain how the NIB file (and a few other scary ideas) create leverage. It is that leverage that enables one guy in his basement to compete with a team of engineers at Microsoft or Adobe. It is like I showed a chain saw to a early American colonist, and he said, "Can I cut down the tree without starting the engine? I don't like the noise. Maybe I can just bang it against the tree?"

Yes, it's hard to generalize after reading specific tutorials, but you will learn. I thought the learning curve was insurmountable when I first started, but if I can become a programmer that gets paid to write Cocoa software, you can too. Just keep reading and practicing. Don't fight the tools--use them.

Comment: If you create Views on the fly, according to the user request, and if those Views contents are also organized according to the user request, IB makes it confusing and hard (if not impossible) to achieve. I understand your point but I don't think IB should be a dogma. It depends on what you want to achieve. Moreover, i think that IB should be out of the way when you learn Xcode programming as i think that you should keep away Dreamweaver when you learn HTML and CSS. It's a helper for sure but not the foundation. My two cents here.

Comment: You are wrong. IB is absolutely part of the foundation. Accept that and move forward from there. Or just keep banging the chainsaw against the tree. It's your choice.

Comment: Don't you find it "extreme" to say that without IB you will NEVER be a successful iOS programmer? Each one his way to learn and this is my way: I need to go to the core of things or I get confused. A graphic interface is always a fancy way of presenting some underlying code. I'm more inspired by the code. You say I'm wrong, I say you see things differently. For each article you will find praying the use of IB, I will find one praying the contrary. Now why don't we just agree that we don't agree? Whatever your opinion, I'm sure you have some insight to share about my questions. Don't hesitate!

Comment: IB is not a code generator. That's a misconception. That's the Visual Studio frame of mind. You will have a very hard time finding an article by a reputable OS X or iOS programmer who advocates not using IB. You don't have to believe me, but you really should believe Aaron Hillegass. Good luck.

Comment: Last question I read regarding this matter of IB or not IB, this is what happened:"This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion".

Comment: This clearly means it's a matter of opinion. I'm sorry though that there's so much waste of time and energy trying to say how much the world is black and white (mostly white from your point of view) when this energy would've been greatly appreciated if it were used to answer the questions.

Comment: You're right. If you're just not going to listen it was a waste of my time and energy.

Comment: Listening is one thing, agreeing is another, sir. I heard you and I heard other opinions from persons who have also a certain expertise. Now, who I follow is my prerogative and I'm sorry if I don't agree with you.You made your case and I listened. Please consider this waste on both sides. But I thank you anyway for trying to get me "straight".

Comment: Not to stir up anything here in this heated discussion, but even if you create views dynamically there is still a lot of value in having IB define where the views will go, or define sets of views that you can use.  I would say you can be a successful IOS programmer without using IB, but as SSteve says IB gives you a huge amount of leverage - with newer incarnations, even more so.  You can also (to borrow his analogy) be successful in chopping down a tree with an unpowered chainsaw, it will just take a lot longer...

Comment: What bothers me is that if I decide to take the "long way", It doesn't mean I'm not eligible for help. A long way that pleases you is always better than the short one you will quit at some point. I tried to learn with IB and quit several times as I didn't feel the thing. Now I give Xcode another try without IB and I hang on and enjoy it. It makes more sense to me and, so far, does the job just as fine. So, what's the best thing? Quit or take the long way? One thing is for sure, the more people will insist in me doing things their way and retaining their knowledge, the longer the road will be.

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist on going without IB (and I agree 100% with SSteve) then in addition to the files you list you will also want to use a UIViewController. Now, it is important to know that you only need to create header and implementation files when you are adding or changing default behavior.

In you case, the view can probably just be a generic UIView, so you wouldn't need the files. What you would do is subclass UIViewController, and put the swipe logic there. In the swipe logic code you would probably just change the background color of the view.

You would instantiate the view controller in the delegate (in this case anyway) and create the view in the view controller's loadView method. That is required since you won't be using IB.

Personally though, I think that IB does a great job of encouraging proper MVC patterns, and if you are just starting then you should go with IB.

Answer (score 0):

In practice you mostly do not make classes for views, unless they need to do custom drawing or display.

For lightweight configuration of views, that is often done in the viewController's viewDidLoad (or I guess in your case loadView) method.

Yes it's a good idea to keep model and view separated, but that's also balanced with the equally good idea to reduce the amount of code that exists.  The less code that is written, the fewer bugs you will have.

Since you are just starting out at this point I would absolutely start by using ARC, and using IB - even though I'm sure you're tired of hearing that from everyone, I'll give you an alternate take.  Less code means fewer bugs.  And the fact that so many experienced developers are telling you to use it should be a giant clue about what a productive path forward is.  I mean, are you doing this to build applications or learn every corner of the UIView class?

To speak to your code example, you do not need the UIView custom class.  Just create use a UIViewController's main view as a container view, place a UIView inside with the background set to red.  On swipe (using a gesture recognizer attached to the container view) call the UIVew method to swap in a new green-background UIView for the existing red view, you can even define the transition style.

Or create a scroll view in the container view, set up the red and green view inside the scroll view, set the content size and enable paging on the scrollview.

Or create a custom UIView class as you had, listen for touch events and slowly adjust two subview positions to follow the drag action.

Or use an OpenGL backed view, and based on the gesture recognizer pan the scene you are observing with two triangles for a green rectangle and two triangles for a red rectangle.

Comment: Thank you! This is enlightening.To answer to "...are you doing this to build applications or learn every corner of the UIView class", let's say it's a professional habit. I'm a teacher. In my job, any part of what I claim must be explainable. I ended up thinking this way. This is why the copy/paste factor of tutorials don't suit me and also why "delegating" some work to an interface which obfuscate what happens behind the scene bothers me a great deal. Hello, my name is Baylock and I'm a control freak...

Comment: Baylock, you should be using assembly code then. ;) [To be more constructive, I've now updated my answer to try and actually answer your questions.]

Comment: Saw it and answered it! You know, the ASM thing, I really gave it a thought :-) Not there yet but I'll come to it...eventually. Thank you for your answer, once again.